# Socket - Queue System design implementation in java

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, sockets, queue

I'm working in the core of a system right now, but I'm designing the way I'm going to get the information, below the facts:

1. the system will get 8000000 Transactions per day at the begining
2. High availability
3. The moment the information is sent and processed can't take more that 5 seconds, so performance is a critical factor

The idea so far, is to have a socket which gets all the information, in the socket create a producer and using regex to check the message structure (so the system is not overloaded with useless info, if It's okay check what type of message is and send it to the respective Queue (there would be two queues for two differente systems), the consumer would be deployed in a Wildfly 10 cluster.

My question: is this a good approach to implement this? Client -> Socket -> Producer -> Queue -> Consumers - > Cores, having into account performance and availability, all the core of the app will be deployed in the same server in a cluster (min 5 instances), but two different projects

Or should I send all the information to the same queue and in the consumer call the right Service, but I would have to do some kind of verification to know what to call, the information is basically Strings and they info is separated by an element, i.e. | (pipes)

Comment: 'In the socket create a producer' doesn't mean anything.  Are there replies to these messages? Too broad.

Comment: I agree with EJP.  This question is too vague / unclear, and too generic to allow us to give you a meaningful answer.  And even if it was more specific, I think that the best answer would be "create a performance prototype and test it".